# How to delete "Others" file downloaded from UC Browser?

Tags: error, uc-browser

i need some help. I downloaded a .zip file in the UC Browser, but, when i tried to open, the browser showed a error that i don't remember, and the file, dissapeared! Now he is on the "Others" section. My phone is a Lumia 535, WP 8.1.**Problem Solved.**

Comment: Have you tried deleting it from an attached pc?

Comment: I didn't found this file while attached to the pc...

Comment: If the "problem solved" part of your question indicates that you fixed the problem, you ought to consider answering your own question so that others can benefit from your experience.